# How to start a newly added supervisor without restarting the server in erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

We have a server running on the remote node. Now we want to add a new feature(implemented by gen_*) without stopping the server. So I use rpc:call(Node, my_sup, start_link, []) to start the supervisor. But unfortunately I found that the supervisor are linked to my local shell instead of the remote node, and it failed immediately (the sup process was killed) after the rpc:call.

I just wonder are there any other ways to start a newly added supervisor dynamically and remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervisors always have to be linked to something. Usually, OTP application in its `start` method spawns "root supervisor" that supervises all other processes and other supervisors. It is linked to process starting the application.

If you have such a root supervisor, you can use `supervisor:start_child(SupRef, ChildSpec)`. `SupRef` is a reference to the "root supervisor" (it might be a Pid or a name) and `ChildSpec` would be the supervisor, you want to spawn or the gen_server itself. This function is documented here:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2

If you don't have a supervision tree. You can package new feature as an OTP application, which spawns the first supervisor on start.